# In salesforce mobile app i am unable to show the error msg when they not turned on the location

Tags: geolocation, salesforce

```
 $scope.showButtons = function () {
            if(!window.navigator.onLine){
                $scope.showToast("Please check your internet connection","error");
            }
             else
             {  
                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                     
                     Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                         '{!$RemoteAction.AngularWithVfPage.doStartEnd}',
                         latitude,
                         longitude,
                         function(result, event) {
                             if (event.status) {
                                 if (result && result.Id) {
                                     $scope.DailyLog = result;
                                     $scope.showToast("Day Started!!!","success");
                                 } 
                                 else
                                 {
                                     $scope.showToast("Day Already Started!!!","success");
                                 }
                             } else {
                                 alert('Error checking DailyLog: ' + event.message);
                             }
                             $scope.$apply();
                         }
                     );
                 },function (error) {
                     switch (error.code) {
                         case 1:
                             $scope.showToast("Geolocation request denied by user.", "error");
                             break;
                         case 2:
                             $scope.showToast("Geolocation position unavailable.", "error");
                             break;
                         case 3:
                             $scope.showToast("Please Turn on Your Location", "info");
                             break;
                         default:
                             $scope.showToast("Geolocation error: " + error.message, "error");
                     }
                     $scope.$apply(); 
                 },
                  { timeout: 5500 });
                 $scope.showList = true;
             }
        };
```

**In salesforce mobile app i am unable to show the error msg when they not turned on the location
tried some if conditions if location positions not available but when location not available no code is running that time out is working but not good enough **